# Select last record from similar in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table in DB, with following columns:

- action_type
- file_id
- time

Now, I need to select all actions with particular type and time and use file_id to delete file. The problem is that I might get several rows from that query, but I only need one, which was last added to DB.

Suppose the example records in DB:

```
_id = 1, action_type = 1, file_id= 1, time = 1000
_id = 2, action_type = 1, file_id= 1, time = 2000
_id = 3, action_type = 1, file_id= 1, time = 3000
_id = 4, action_type = 1, file_id= 2, time = 1000
_id = 5, action_type = 1, file_id= 2, time = 2000
_id = 6, action_type = 1, file_id= 2, time = 3000
```

Now, I only need records with _id=3 and _id=6. How do I construct such query?

Note: I'm using SQLite.

Comment: How "particular" is your time? As long as you can ensure that there can not be 2 records with the same time for the same file, then just select where MAX(time).

Comment: It would be wrong if you got `_id`, 1 and 5 for example although they have the right file_id? If `time` on #6 was lower than 3000, would you still want to get it included in the result? Or only those that have the absolute latest timestamp (i.e. equal to max(time))?

Comment: @kasoban, time is completely random.

Comment: @zapl I only need records with latest timestamp, but I need those for each group(i.e with same file_id and action_type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you can get the latest recored for all distinct file_id. Normally, this request should work fine in sqlite :

```
SELECT file_id, 
       _id, 
       action_type, 
       Max(time) 
FROM   test 
GROUP  BY file_id;
```

Edit :

Ok, your request is more complex :

```
SELECT `_id`, `action_type`, `file_id`, `time` FROM testtable t1
GROUP BY file_id
HAVING time = (
    SELECT MAX(time) FROM testtable t2 
    WHERE t2.file_id = t1.file_id
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9f936/2

Comment: That will return you a more or less random `_id` & `action_type` from the group. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f9364/2/0 - not the ones from the row that contains the max(time) value.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, please see my comment to @zapl answer.

Comment: With my new response, it should return the max time for each different file_type. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b4e75/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to get this result:

```
SELECT _id, file_id
FROM table t
WHERE action_type = x 
    AND t.time = (SELECT Max(time) 
                     FROM Table s
                     WHERE s.action_type = t.action_type
                       AND s.file_id = t.file_id)
```

See the following link for how to use subqueries:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm

Answer (score 1):

If your table does not contain the same timestamp twice per file you could simply use

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE time = (SELECT max(time) FROM yourtable)
```

There is no need to group by `file_id` or bother about it because there can't be more than 1 entry per file with that timestamp.

```
_ID     ACTION_TYPE     FILE_ID     TIME
------------------------------------------------
  3               1           1     3000
  6               1           2     3000
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f9364/5/0

Comment: Sorry, my sample data was ambiguous, time is random. In your example if the time of rows is different, I will only get row with max time. What I need is to divide rows in groups with same FILE_ID and ACTION_TYPE, and than select row with max time from each group.

Comment: Oh ok. That would be different and a little more complex.